# React Native - returned response error code: 500- Unable to resolve module. This might be related to error react-native/issues/4968

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: first screenshot]
[image: second screenshot]
[image: third screenshot]
[image: fourth screenshot]

[image: error screenshot]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'; 

export default class ChatHomeScreen extends Component { 
    render() { 
     var {navigate} = this.props.navigation; 
     return ( <View style={styles.container}> <Text>Welcome to Chat Screen</Text> </View> ); } } 
     const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', justifyContent: 'center', } 
    });
```

Don't know where I am wrong.As soon as I remove this ChatHomeScreen related code (import, return ) app works fine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code related to ChatHomescreen

Comment: @GabrielMesquita-  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class ChatHomeScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>        
        <Text>Welcome to Chat Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});

Comment: @GabrielMesquita - Could you please formate this for me .. the code is in screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a slash in the import:

.src should be ./src.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer so it does not go unsolved. Thanks